Ubuntu 22.04 installation failed
I was trying to install Ubuntu instead of Windows, so I followed this video https://youtu.be/hNYH7xkdYYQ?si=o0zuvajqRWws6Ik- , but I am now stuck at booting at this error and can't go farther. I tried to reinstall, but got the same thing.


I can see half of "Started unattended upgrades ..." at the very edge of the image - something that I suspect might take a good while...

sorry for late answer
i managed to pass this problem i think it was nvidea drivers or something like this
i reinstalled ubuntu but without (option) downloading third party and etc programs  it succeeded then installed it after that
